# Is this the correct site to ask about the original meaning of a foreign language surname?

Tags: discussion

It is well known that a large number of European surnames, in a wide variety of languages, originated are words with specific meanings. Obvious examples in English are:

- Smith
- Taylor
- Brown
- etc.

The question is, given the genealogical expertise on this site, whether it is the correct site to make inquiries on such.

Further, if the answer might generally be "No" for a site such as [German Language](https://german.stackexchange.com/) where a language stack already exists, are exceptions made for languages such as **Dutch** where no such stack exists at original time of posting?